# Material design - What is the correct size for icon in listview?

Tags: android, android-gui

What is the correct size for icon in listview to follow material design guidelines ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`24dp﻿` is the correct size for icon in `ListView`

Comment: You can find the specification [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Comment: @chulo what about size icon in another place for example in toolbars an in button in tabs and ...

Comment: If anyone needs to know in pixels [Online Dip Converter](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter)

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling so hard to have an official answer to this question in the material design site, which is really not user friendly when you are a developer searching for simple informations concerning every sizes and margins...

I think you can find the specs in the system icons section :
[Icons guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#)